# PHP code not connecting HTML to MYsql database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm new to PHP ...... so I want to make a program in which my HTML form inputs are stored in the database. I followed a [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qm4Eih_2p-M) to do this this and here is the code I have written for the php file `<?php

```
$firstname = $_POST ['firstname'] ;
$email = $_POST ['email'];
$admin = $_POST ['admin'];
$school = $_POST ['school'];
$gender = $_POST ['gender'] ;

//DATABASE CONECTION
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'register');
if ($conn-> connect_error){
die ('connection error    :  ' . $conn-> connect_error);
}else{
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO register(firstname, email, admin, gender)
values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt-> bind_param("ssiss", $firstname, $email, $admin, $gender);
$stmt-> execute();
echo"Registration succesfull";
$stmt-> close();
$conn-> close();
}`
```

and here is my database

[image]

and my html code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>form</title>    
</head>
<body>
    <h1>
      <div>  <center>Trial form</center> 
    </h1>
     
        <form action="connect.php" method="post"> 
           <center> <label for="name"><b>enter name</b> </label> <br>
            <input type="text" name="first name" id="firstname"> <br>
            <br>
            <label for="email"><b>email</b></label><br>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email"> <br>
            <br>
            <label for="admin no."><b> enter admin no. </b></label><br>
            <input type="number" name="admin" id="admin"> <br> 
            <label for="school"><b>enter school name</b></label> <br>
            <input type="text" name="school" id="school"> <br> 
            <label for="school"><b>Gender</b></label> <br>
            
            <label for="male"> <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="m"><b>male</b></label> <br>
            <label for="female"><input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="f"><b>female</b></label><br>
                   
       <input type="submit" value="submit"><br>
        </form> <center>
        </div>
            <body bgcolor="#fcba03">
                <body text="#000000"

            
</body>
</html>
```

When I run it, the HTML form runs fine but the PHP program is just displayed on the screen without any output. pls help me thanks.
to fix this i have tried rewriting the php code.
i tried debugging the php code but this the error it gave me `Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\Users\Dell\connect.php on line 10 connection error    :  Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`
(i used my mysql password to connect it)
this is my html code while running
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztmv6.png)
and this is my php code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwjC2.png)
i also keep getting this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on bool in C:\Users\Dell\connect.php:14
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in C:\Users\Dell\connect.php on line 14
```

Comment: What **exactly** is not working? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is this problem really related to HTML? You haven't shared any HTM markup, nor the form that is used to send data to this script

Comment: actually there is the html code as png i have tried re writing the code too

Comment: You've missed to add the `school` column to your query. According to your screen shot, that column can't be null and has no default value, so you must add it as well.

Comment: @M.Eriksson i rectified the error still doesnt seem to work

Comment: The error from mysql states that root has a password so find the password for root and use it in your database connection. Currently, based on the code you have shown above, root has no password

Comment: According to the error you just posted, you seem to be using the wrong database credentials so your code never even reaches the query. For future reference, _always_ do proper debugging before asking a question and then _always_ include all relevant code and error messages! We can only help you if we have the full picture. Otherwise we will just waste time guessing.

Comment: @DankyiAnnoKwaku    already did that i was going to mention that mysql is on a different port so i mentioned that in the code

Comment: @M.Eriksson yes its my bad actually its my first q on here so... ill be careful from next time

Comment: **Syntax**: mysqli_connect(host, username, password, dbname, **port**, socket), where port and socket are optional , but in your case port is mandatory because you are not using standard 3306 port

Comment: On the other hand, do **NOT** post your actual password in SO please. Mask it by ***** or use photoshop to erase it if you are posting an image

Comment: @KenLee i have made those changes and i know that i shouldnt post my password so thats why i have just written about it

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are providing four values but asking for five.
Try this:

```
   $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO register(firstname, email, admin, gender)
values(?, ?, ?, ?)"); // removed the last '?'

$stmt-> bind_param("ssis", $firstname, $email, $admin, $gender); // removed a 's' from the parameters data type
```

Comment: actually i accidently did not add variable for the school placeholder but still doesnt work thanks though